# Difference between 2 Dates PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL to make queries. I would like to get the difference in days between the current date and a certain date column in a table.

I use this query:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(D, Minimum_date, Current_date) AS active_date 
FROM
   (SELECT posting_id, media_cycle_id, MIN(external_date_created) AS "Minimum_date"
   (SELECT cmc.site_id, cmc.media_cycle_id, cp.posting_id, cp_job_id, cp.external_date_created
    FROM  landing.advertising_context_media_cycle as cmc
    INNER JOIN landing.advertising_context_posting as cp
             ON cmc.cycle_id=cp.cycle_id) AS A
    GROUP BY posting_id, media_cycle_id) B) AS cap_date
```

The error message says that `D` does not exist.
When I remove `D`, it says `"Minimum_date"` does not exist although it is present in the query.

Comment: SQL Server != PostrgreSQL != MySQL - please ensure you only tag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: I have already edited tag postgreSQL only.

Comment: In postgres `"Minimum_date"` is case sensitive. Without the quotes, it's folded to lowercase, so the outer `Minimum_date` actually refers to a non-existing `minimum_date`. Either use lowercase names with no quotes, or use quotes.

Comment: @Zegarek I have already corrected it. The first error shown is the use of D to mean the difference in days. The error says column "d" does not exist. I have made research about my syntax, and so far this one is correct based on my research. I have no more ideas how to do about it.

Comment: a) [there is no `datediff` function in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F15%2F&q=datediff) b) even [if there was](https://www.narratordata.com/blog/postgres-missing-datediff-function/), the first argument would be a string `'d'` not a column reference `D` c) what Zegarek said

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I have tried this format DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - minimum_date) but it does not work still. The error says the operator does not exist: date -text.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) subtracting two dates will return an integer with the number of days

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract two dates from each other to get the difference in days as an integer number. Removing unnecessary aliases and with some other improvements you get:

```
SELECT *, CURRENT_DATE - minimum_date AS active_date 
FROM (
    SELECT posting_id, media_cycle_id, MIN(external_date_created) AS minimum_date
    FROM (
        SELECT cmc.media_cycle_id, cp.posting_id, cp.external_date_created
        FROM landing.advertising_context_media_cycle AS cmc
        JOIN landing.advertising_context_posting AS cp USING (cycle_id) )
    GROUP BY posting_id, media_cycle_id )
```

As per several comments, identifiers are forced to lowercase unless they are double-quoted. That means that you need to do that consistently if you start with it.